# MYSQL insert into multiple tables doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I have three files reg_form.php, dbconnection.php and insert.php. 
When submitting the form the data is not inserted into the database.  I can't figure out why.  Initially I didn't know how to use insert into multiple tables but took the advice of many posts from here.  Unfortunately I have still failed to make it work and it is driving me insane.  Here is the sql code so far  for the insert.

```
<?php
include ("dbconnection.php");

if(file_exists("dbconnection.php")) {
echo"Connected to database successfully";
} else if(!file_exists("dbconnection.php")){
echo "Connection failed";  
}
    $forename = "forename";
    $surname = "surname";
    $address_line1 = "address_line1";
    $address_line2 = "address_line2";
    $address_line3 = "address_line3";
    $city = "city";
    $postcode = "postcode";
    $phone = "phone";
    $email = "email"; 
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $cpassword = "cpassword ";


    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, 
    password)VALUES('$username','$password');";
    $query2 = "INSERT INTO users_details (forename, surname,address_line1, 
            address_line2, address_line3, city, postcode, phone, email)
            VALUES('$forename','$surname','$address_line1','$address_line2',
            '$address_line3','$city','$postcode','$phone','$email')";
    query ($dbconnection,$sql);
    ?>
```

Comment: Your main problems are you're calling a function called `query()` which I'm sure isn't a database query function, are you using PDO or mysqli? Second is you're using `$sql` in your query and this is not seen used in any part of the code provided.

Comment: Really unsure why checking the file exists means the database connection worked.  If you want to make sure it's used - change `include` to `require`.  This still doesn't mean the connection worked.

Comment: Parameterize your query you are open to SQL injections. Hash the user's passwords.

Comment: Ok, so I took your advice used PDO and tested the db connection but now I get Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in  line 21. this is the code
$insert = $con->prepare ("INSERT INTO users_details (forename, surname,address_line1, 
                address_line2, address_line3, city, postcode, phone, email)
                VALUES(:forename, :surname, :address_line1, :address_line2,
                :address_line3, :city, :postcode, :phone, :email) ");
                "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
                VALUES(:username,:password)";

Comment: So now I got rid of the error by include ("dbconnection.php");
include ("reg_form.php"); in the insert page.  I now get no errors but my data is not inserting into the database on submit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem is solved.  I made a stored procedure because I am doing an INSERT INTO multiple tables and then called it like this.
       $sql ="CALL add_user('".$username."', '".$password."', 'user', 
       '".$forename."','".$surname."', '".$address_line1."' , 
       '".$address_line2."', '".$address_line3."', '".$city."', '".$postcode."', 
       '".$phone."', '".$email."','".is_bool($email_contact)."', 
       '".is_bool($phone_contact)."')";
        $query = $con->prepare($sql);

```
    $query->execute();
```